# Realtime zoom from AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-camera

I am implementing a camera application. I initiate the camera as follows:

```
  let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
  captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
  captureSession?.addInput(input)
  videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
  videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
  videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
  previewView.layer.insertSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
```

Now I want to have a small rectangle on top of the preview layer. In that rectangle area, I want to zoom a specific area from the preview layer. To do it, I add a new UIView on top of other views, but I don't know how to display a specific area from the previewer (e.g. zoom factor = 2).
The following figure shows what I want to have:
[image]
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.
The idea is to extract the real-time frames from the output of the camera, then use an UIImage view to show the enlarged frame. Following is the portion of code to add an video output:

```
let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer"))
guard captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) else { return }
captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
```

and we need to implement a delegate function:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    guard let uiImage = imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer) else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
      self.delegate?.captured(image: uiImage)
    }
}

private func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
    guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return nil }
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return nil }
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}
```

The code was taken from this [article](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-camera-frames-extraction-d2c0f80ed05a).

Comment: Using this code are you able to zoom on particular Line which is drawn in middle ?

Comment: Of course, just take the real-time output, zoom it then put it into a UIImageView

Comment: But its not feasible i guess.Like if i get image each second and set it to imageview ,it would create memory leakage

Comment: Yah its working actually i have not written CGImageRelease that's why it was creating memory leakage